# how to fetch continuous occurrence count of a column value in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have added one more id column for the order purpose, if the table is like this

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | cs_id |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | a     |
|   2 | b     |
|   3 | a     |
|   4 | a     |
|   5 | a     |
|   6 | b     |
|   7 | b     |
|   8 | b     |    
|   9 | b     | 
+-----+-------+
```

i want the continuous occurrence of cs_id order by id column

```
+-----+-------+---------------------------------
| id  | cs_id |    continuous_occurrence_cs_id 
+-----+-------+---------------------------------|
|   1 | a     |    1 
|   2 | b     |    1 
|   3 | a     |    1 
|   4 | a     |    2 
|   5 | a     |    3 
|   6 | b     |    1 
|   7 | b     |    2
|   8 | b     |    3
|   9 | b     |    4 
+-----+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: 1) Which database/version are you using. 2) On what basis are you ordering the data, as there is no guarantee that you will get `cs_id` in same order as you mentioned in the post

Comment: can you explain your requirement further?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -> Thanks for the tag. Never heard about this tag, but previous questions were similar to this particular requirement.

Comment: Thank Utsav & Migs.  
Okay now i have added one more id column for the order purpose, if the table is like this

id  cs_id   
---  ----       
1 a        
2 b  
3 a  
4 a  
5 a  
6 b  
7 b  
8 b  
9 b  

i want the continuous occurrence of cs_id order by id column 

id  cs_id    continuous_occurenence_cs_id
---  ----       ----------------------------
1 a  1
2 b  1
3 a  1
4 a  2
5 a  3
6 b  1
7 b  2
8 b  3
9 b  4

Comment: @Alok You can [edit] your question to replace the table with the one with an ordering column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in SQL by the definition data has no any order unless the `ORDER BY`is used.
See: [Wikipedia - Order By](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by)

> ORDER BY is the only way to sort the rows in the result set. 
> Without
>   this clause, the relational database system may return the rows in any
>   order.

You must provide an additional column to your table that determines the order, and can be used in `ORDER BY` clause, for example`RN` column in the below example:

```
        RN CS_ID     
---------- ----------
         1 a         
         2 b         
         3 a         
         4 a         
         5 a         
         6 b         
         7 b         
         8 b         
         9 b
```

---

For the above data you can use Common Table Expression (recursive query) to get required result, for example the below query works on Oracle database:

```
WITH my_query( RN, cs_id , cont ) AS (

    SELECT t.rn, t.cs_id, 1
        FROM My_table t
        WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.rn, t.cs_id,
         case when t.cs_id = m.cs_id
              then m.cont + 1
              else 1
         end
        FROM My_table t
        JOIN my_query m
        ON t.rn = m.rn + 1
)
select * from my_query
order by rn;

        RN CS_ID            CONT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 a                   1
         2 b                   1
         3 a                   1
         4 a                   2
         5 a                   3
         6 b                   1
         7 b                   2
         8 b                   3
         9 b                   4
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact output i want